# Hiding requests of Flash movie from browser

Tags: php, javascript, actionscript-3, flash, httprequest

I have my own flash video player that makes a request to a video file on my server. I use Google Chrome and every time when I use Inspect Element and go to the Network tab, I see that request. So the advanced users can see it too and download the video. How can I protect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is no surefire way to prevent users downloading anything you put on your website. Users who are advanced enough **will** find a way. However, this is a technique I've used in the past to fetch the Flash file server-side:

```
index.php:

<?php session_start(); ?>
... HTML head stuff
<?php $_SESSION['swf'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
... HTML stuff
<object classid="somestuff" style="height:720px;width:1280px;" id="pmv_september">
    <param name="movie" value="swf.php?v=1">
</object>
... More HTML stuff
```

I haven't figured out how to make this work on IE pre-10, I'm sure there's a way but I don't know what it is. So, what I do after this is have a database, so I can pass the 'v' parameter to the database and get the right video file:

```
swf.php

<?php

$videoId = $_GET['v'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['swf']) {
    die('Try harder');
}

// Attempt to prevent caching
unset($_SESSION['swf']);
header('Cache-control: no-cache');
header('Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash');

// Get the video
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','database');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT url FROM videos WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bind_param('i',$videoid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();

// Pass video to the client
readfile($result);

?>
```

I vaguely recall that this code is based on something I found online, so if anyone knows where the original is, please edit this to give them credit. I had a quick look around and couldn't find it but as this site was first implemented in 2008, that's not necessarily surprising.

This works with `url` outside www root, so it's a way to keep all your FLVs in a hard to find place.

Comment: That's a really nice way! Thank you, I'll try it :)